# Trying to understand Wi-Fi Speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

My ISP provides Wi-Fi download at 100 Mbps.

My MacBook Wi-Fi card does 802.11ac, which can support up to 1 Gbps.
It gets 100-118 Mbps over the internet, according to speedtest.net.
OK, Cool.

My iMac has 802.11n which can support up to 300 Mbps.
Sitting right next to the MacBook, it gets 66 Mbps on speedtest.net.

Why would the iMac running 802.11n not get the 100-116 Mbps, since it is well below the expected speed of 300 Mbps of the 802.11n?

Obviously my home network can deliver at that speed, since the MacBook is getting 100 Mbps over its Wi-Fi card.
The SNR is the same in both instances.
The location is the same in both instances.

What is the variable other than N versus AC, since both support greater than the 100 Mbps the network is capable of?

If I turn Wi-Fi off on the iMac, and plug it into my router, it gets 100-116 Mbps.

Comment: Are you using the exact same version of the exact same browser on each machine? Different browsers - and even different versions of the same browser - calculate and measure packets differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's not rare in wifi modules performance to be crippled by bad drivers or even hardware bugs, but since I do not expect this from Apple let's rule out this possibility.

It might be an interference problem. If you off WiFi on MacBook, does iMac's connection gets better?
Try to perform "Wireless Diagnostics" to find which channels around are crowded and which are best to be used. Switch your AP to a the best advised channel and see if it helps.

Steps to follow:

1. Hold down the OPTION key and click the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar.
2. Choose *Open Wireless Diagnostics*.
3. Pull down the *Windows* menu and choose *Utilities*.
4. Select the *Wi-Fi Scan* tab, and select *Scan Now*.

When finished, look at the bottom right for the best channels recommendations:

```
Best 2.4 GHz Channels (usually 802.11b/g)
Best 5 GHz Channels (usually 802.11a/n)
```

Now log in to your wi-fi router (this is going to vary depending on the manufacturer) and make the channel changes as necessary – typically this means using a web browser to point at the local router IP (192.168.0.1, etc). There you shall find AP specific settings, if you have both 2.4GHz and 5 GHz access points you should set channels for them independently. Set recommended channels, reboot router, try your connection again.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for pointing out, added step-by-step guide. Hope it clears up things a bit.

Comment: As @metamorphling noted, another variable is the frequency band: 2.4GHz vs. 5. Is your router dual band? Does the iMac work at 5 or 2.4 GHz?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for such a detailed response.  Unfortunately I had done all that before I posted.  I have the optimized channels on 2.4 and 5